# Solution of a specific integral using the Cauchy Integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have a question regarding a integral I just can't find the right solution to. It's this beauty:

$$\int_\gamma \frac{\cos(\pi z)}{z^2+1} dz$$ where $\gamma = 3 \cdot e^{it}$. 
 
I used the Cauchy Integral Formula (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem)) with $n=0$, $a=1$ and $f(z) = \frac{\cos(\pi z)}{z+1}$ and it got me a result of $-\pi i$. However, this integral should be zero according to my professor. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to use partial fraction decomposition to write your function in the form $$\frac{\cos ( \pi z )}{z^2+1} = \frac{A(z)}{z+i} +\frac{B(z)}{z-i}$$ then use Cauchy Integral formula.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any advanced Complex Analysis theorems to compute that integral. Let $f(z)=\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{z^2+1}$. In order to compute $\oint_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz$, all that I will need is that $f$ is integrable and even. In fact, $\oint_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz$ is equal to $\int_0^{2\pi}f(3e^{it})3ie^{it}\,\mathrm dt$, which, in turn, is equal to $3i$ times$$\int_0^\pi f(3e^{it})e^{it}\,\mathrm dt+\int_\pi^{2\pi}f(3e^{it})e^{it}\,\mathrm dt.\tag1$$But\begin{align}\int_\pi^{2\pi}f(3e^{it})e^{it}\,\mathrm dt&=\int_0^\pi f\left(3i^{i(t+\pi)}\right)e^{i(t+\pi)}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^\pi f\left(-3e^{it}\right)\left(-e^{it}\right)\,\mathrm dt\\&=-\int_0^\pi f\left(3e^{it}\right)e^{it}\,\mathrm dt,\end{align}since $f$ is an even function. So, $(1)$ is equal to $0$, and therefore $\oint_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me as to how you applied CIF for you function $f$. To apply CIF you need an analytic function.

Poles are at $\pm i$ and the  residues are $\cos (\pi i)=\frac {e^{-1}+e^{1}}{2 i}$ and $\cos (-\pi i)=\frac {e^{-1}+e^{1}}{ -2i }$. So the integral is $0$ by Residue Theorem.